# "All (the) students of the first year are invited" - what difference does the definite article make?

Tags: definite-article

1) All the students of the first year are invited.
2) All students of the first year are invited.
[ what does  first and second sentences mean with and without the ]

Comment: In your context, why do you think there is any difference? Honestly though, "All first year students are invited." would be more natural, and avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the two sentences are almost identical in meaning. I would not use "the", as it is slightly shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think that " All 'the' students of the first year are invited" is the correct sentence. The article 'the' should be used with the students as well as the first year.